# Get webpart's Zone Id via CSOM

Tags: web-part, client-object-model, web-part-zone

How to get Web Part Zone Id via CSOM? WebPart has property [ZoneIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpart.zoneindex%28v=office.15%29.aspx) but no ZoneId while WebPartDefinition has method [MoveWebPartTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.webparts.webpartdefinition.movewebpartto%28v=office.15%29.aspx)(string zoneID, int zoneIndex) but lacks methods to retrieve the ZoneId.

server-side API has [WebPart.ZoneID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.webpart.zoneid.aspx).

Comment: Same for REST it seems, ref: `/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/SitePages/Home.aspx')/GetLimitedWebPartManager()/WebParts`

Comment: sorry for the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those just finding this now, the current version (16.1) of the Microsoft SharePoint Online client object model now includes this property on the `WebPartDefinition` class.

http://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365

Note that this doesn't yet work on-prem, as the server side components don't yet expose this property.

Comment: The property always contains the `Uninitialized` error ...  I opened a question about it here https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235824/unable-to-access-webpartdefinition-zoneid-property

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by yourself using standard JavaScript or jQuery.

I show you an example how to recognize Web Part Zone Id.

So if we have a page layout like this:

[image]

Then we will have a page like this:

[image]

That is how the DOM looks like:

[image]
[image]

What I suppose is that the **MSOZoneCell_** is a standard prefix then after that is the Zone Id. So you can use that on your method to move your web part around.

Comment: Do you have idea how to retrieve the Zone Id (ZoneID property) specifically?

Comment: What about using the zoneIndex property of the SP.WebParts.WebPart object ?

Comment: ZoneIndex defines the order number inside a Zone, while ZoneID defines the Zone. For example, the third web part in "Left" web part zone has ZoneID "Left" and ZoneIndex 2.

Comment: I got you point... let me edit the answer and show you how to do that

Comment: I am accessing SharePoint from a remote server using client-side object model (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll). If it is not possible to get ZoneID that way I think my secondary choice would be to use web services (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa979489(v=office.12).aspx) where it seems to be possible to get the ZoneID at least for web parts which allow us to export the property values.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API url needs to have the site url with full `/sites/BusinessServices/` etc.

```
 https://TENANT/sites/HomePortal/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/HomePortal/Pages/ProductInfo.aspx')
```

And then need the `personalizationscope` when getting webparts :

```
 https://TENANT/sites/HomePortal/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/HomePortal/Pages/ProductInfo.aspx')/GetLimitedWebPartManager(1)
```

0 = Shared
1 = User

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, using the SharePoint API.

```
var instance = SP.Ribbon.WebPartComponent.get_instance();
if (!instance.selectWebPartById(<id attribute from webpart element>) continue;
var zoneId = SP.Ribbon.WebPartComponent.get_activeWebPartZoneId();
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the page for editing.  Select the web part zone you want to know the ID for.

In the debug window, paste this:

```
var zoneId = SP.Ribbon.WebPartComponent.get_activeWebPartZoneId();
```

Thanks to Robbert Helling for getting me most of the way there

Comment: This always returns null for me